# Print values from HashMap

Tags: kotlin

Currently, I am trying to write a method to locate the highest value product in my hashmap.

I am looking for a push in the right direction if that is possible. I appreciate any help that might be pointed my way. Thank you.

Comment: `highestPricedProduct` is a `Map.Entry` , you have to use proper formated way to print using `String.format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maxBy returns nullable Map.Entry so you need to handle nullable result. You could for example use safe call with ? following by let as below.

```
 products.maxBy { it.value.second }?.let {
    val (key, value) = it
    println("The highest priced product is: ")
    println()
    println("Item#    Description      Price")
    println("-----    -------------    -------")
    println("$key ${value.first} ${value.second}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be consistent, I would suggest you using horizontal tab `\t` as the divider.

To align the text in the right columns, I would also create a method which adds some whitespaces right after the product name (e.g *jeans*). The number of input whitespaces should be equal to the subtraction of the column title (e.g *Description*) and the product name (e.g *jeans*).

Try this code:

```
fun addWhitespaces(input: String, referencedWord: String = "Description"): String
{
    var ws = ""
    (0..(referencedWord.length - input.length)).map { ws += " " }
    return ws
}
```

The method `addWhitespaces()` is called within the last print.

```
products.maxBy { it.value.second } ?.let { (key, value) ->
    println("The highest priced product is: ")
    println()
    println("Item#\tDescription\tPrice")
    println("-----\t-----------\t-----")
    println("$key \t${value.first}${addWhitespaces(value.first)}\t${value.second}")
}
```

Also as [Ali Gelenler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107967/9723204) mentioned, you should check for the null condition as the result of `maxBy()` may be null.

Comment: `addWhitespaces(a, b)` can be simplified to [`a.padEnd(b.length)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-end.html)

Comment: @pixix4 Oh cool, I didn't know this method exists. Thank you for improving my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is the default format from the map entry. Change your print statement to something like this:

```
println("${highestPricedProduct.key}\t${highestPricedProduct.value.first}\t${highestPricedProduct.value.second}")
```